# Dropzone Existing image preview not showing

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, dropzone.js

I am trying to dispaly existing images from folder to dropzone.But it will not show preview properly.When i checked in inpect element problem is due to url is not converting into base64.

```
 var mockFile = { name: '85N2ouVOO02A1qg150685022765f1e892-8fd1-47d2-a59d-27d94e9c9438.jpg', size: '308386', type:'jpg', url: 'http://localhost/demo/public/blog/blog_post/85N2ouVOO02A1qg150685022765f1e892-8fd1-47d2-a59d-27d94e9c9438.jpg' };

                    dzClosure.emit("addedfile", mockFile);

// And optionally show the thumbnail of the file:
                    dzClosure.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, 'http://localhost/demo/public/blog/blog_post/85N2ouVOO02A1qg150685022765f1e892-8fd1-47d2-a59d-27d94e9c9438.jpg');
```

[image]

[image]

Can any one help me how to show preview and delete option

Comment: Try adding `dzClosure.files.push(mockFile);` before `dzClosure.emit("addedfile", mockFile);`. Is the URL correct? What happens if you click the image source shown in the inspector?

Comment: @azeós.ya url is correct i can access from browser

Comment: stil its not working

Comment: @azeós.as per inspect element its prety sure its not converting inot base64

Comment: I looked at my code and the image is not converted to base64. I don't think that's a problem, could you try to make a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: did you fix this ?